# Cannot Redirect when Logging in an Account using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

Currently, I am developing a website, for my own purposes. I am a beginner at web developing so please understand me if I am not getting this correct. Please Help.

I have a code for javascript when clicking an html element `button`
for logging in. see code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var pword = document.getElementById("password").value;          
        validateUser(username,pword);
    });
});


function validateUser(user,pass){
    var username =user;
    var pword =pass;
    var datasend = "username="+ username + "&password=" + pword;

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../bench/php/login.php',
        data:datasend,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache:false,
        success:function(msg){
            alert("Hello World"); //Trying to pop up
            $('#username').val('');
            $('#pword').val('');
        }
    });
}
```

I successfully triggered the button for the second time I try to click it, and the `hello world` message will pop out, but it cannot redirect the page if it was successfully logged in using an account in MySQL in WAMP server. Here is the code in PHP below:

```
<?php
// require("php/config.php");
include("config.php");
session_start();

if($_POST['username'] != '' && $_POST['password'] !='') {
    // username and password sent from form 
    echo $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
    echo $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

    //$sql = "SELECT user_id  FROM user WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count == 1) {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername; 
        header("Location: index.html");

    } else {
        echo '<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Oops!","Your Account Credentials is Invalid, Please Try Again!","error");';
        echo '}, 100);</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is, the page does not redirect to the `index.html` even when the second click triggers the `HELLO WORLD` alert.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I don't why this is not working, I see the console, there is no error exist.

can someone help me with this? any help will much be appreciated. thanks and regards.

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: There are more issues here. First off, you have an answer that explains why the user isn't redirected. However, even if you would post the form normally (not with ajax), you would still have issues. For some reason, you're echoing the username and password when you escape them. If you do that, you won't be able to use `header()` after since headers needs to be sent before _any_ output at all.

Comment: is it more safe to use just php sir?

Comment: because, I already did the php code for logging in without javascript.

Comment: @BooLaTeh, nah, AJAX is as "safe" as anything else.

Comment: A post is a post. No difference if you do it with Ajax or not. However, using Ajax usually makes better UX since the page don't need to reload on error.

Comment: Wow! Thank you @dearsina I really wanted to do this with javascript. That's why i do this like that. Thanks Again Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to keep to using the AJAX setup you have at the moment (which is totally fine), what you'll need to do is to beef up the on-success function to read the returned results from your PHP.

**A simple example**

Instead of

`header("Location: index.html");`

write

`echo "index.html";
exit;`

and then add the following to your on-success function:

`window.location.href = msg;`

That will start to give you a flavour of how the relationship between an AJAX call and your PHP server should look like.

**Next steps**

1. Instead of having your AJAX return a string (`index.html`) have it
   return an array of information, perhaps you want to welcome the user
   with a personalised message?
2. You don't need to create a string (`var datasend = "username="+ username + "&password=" + pword;`) and feed that to your AJAX call, you can send an array.
3. Make sure your passwords are not stored in plain text on the server.

Comment: Hi Sir! Can I ask a question?

Comment: I have an error on the php code, and it says, undefined index. which is the username and password, how to fix it sir?? I have see the solution, `isset` but it is not working as well

Comment: I have it now sir. Thanks By the way!

Answer (score 0):

An ajax request will not follow the Location header of responses to redirect users.
You need to either redirect the user manually using JS in the success callback or change your form submission to use a [classic HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to make sure, PHP Redirect Header doesn't work when sending an Ajax Request.
So the solution to your problem is:

Change this part of your code in PHP file:

```
header("Location: index.html");
```

Into:

```
echo "Success";
exit();
```

And then in your Ajax Request Success Callback:

```
success:function(msg){
    if (msg == 'Success') {
        window.location = "/path/to/redirect";
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have still confusion in this.